# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado' airnotifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, tornado

I have been facing a problem for a couple of days in installing Airnotifier server on ubuntu machine

1- When I run python --version I got the following screenshot

```
command 'python' not found, did you mean:

command 'python3' from deb python3
command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

2- When I run pip list I could find the package that I want which name is tornado

[image]

followed by this error, I do not know it's reason

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit
    self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1752, in print
    extend(render(renderable, render_options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1390, in render
    for render_output in iter_render:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 134, in __rich_console__
    for line in lines:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/segment.py", line 245, in split_lines
    for segment in segments:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1368, in render
    renderable = rich_cast(renderable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/protocol.py", line 36, in rich_cast
    renderable = cast_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 130, in __rich__
    pip_cmd = get_best_invocation_for_this_pip()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 58, in get_best_invocation_for_this_pip
    if found_executable and os.path.samefile(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 101, in samefile
    s2 = os.stat(f2)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/pip3.8'
Call stack:
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 148, in handle_pip_version_check
    pip_self_version_check(session, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 237, in pip_self_version_check
    logger.info("[present-rich] %s", upgrade_prompt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1446, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 954, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: '[present-rich] %s'
Arguments: (UpgradePrompt(old='22.1.2', new='22.2.2'),)
```

3- and When I tried to run the code I got the following error that tornado is not found

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pushservices.bootstrap import init_messaging_agents
  File "/home/airnotifier/airnotifier/pushservices/bootstrap.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .apns import *
  File "/home/airnotifier/airnotifier/pushservices/apns.py", line 5, in <module>
    from util import json_encode
  File "/home/airnotifier/airnotifier/util.py", line 37, in <module>
    import tornado
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'
```

I tried many ways to install it, but everytime same error

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Comment: @phd ok so sorry, I changes the screenshots to text

Comment: I suggest you use a virtualenv.